# Dealing with Multiple Plugin initializers

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does one best deal with multiple plugin initializers, for example lets say a project is using various components, a general standard setup:

```
 $('#carousel').slick({//options});
 $('#video').vide({//options});
 $('#container').pjax({//options});
 $('#dropdown').dropdown({//options});
```

etc etc. I read mixed reviews on how to deal with such a thing when your calls become to have several options set, and you're loading in up to 7 or 8 of these at a time? Is it better to wrap each of these in a function and from here initialize all once doc ready? Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: Yes, call them on DOM ready for sure, keep them in some self executing initialize function for better readability & modularity. First check which part of the page is visible to user & what are the plugins needed for that part to render & then order the calls to plugins accordingly.